# Getting text and image on same line in header

Tags: html, css

I want the logo on the left hand side of the banner with the two lines of text one above the other on the right hand side of the page, all aligned with each other.

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo img {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo"><img src="image.jpg" alt="image"></div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <h1>Title1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <h4>Title2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using `display: wrap` which isn't valid - Change this to `display: flex` and your flex-container will adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add `float: left;` to `.logo`

Learn more about CSS Floats here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats

Comment: That's right just pull left the logo element and you got it.
I'll show you.
https://jsfiddle.net/8epbn3n4/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use native CSS Grid.

```
 .row {
 width: 100%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout